# Simple Cryptography - Problematic For Loops

Tags: c++, encryption

I'm trying to create a simple cryptography program that allows a user to enter in a 5 letter word as a key. The program then uses each character of that key to encrypt a letter of a user's message that they enter. It's a bit hard to explain, but an example will help make it a bit more clear.

So, say you want your key word to be "lemon". 'l' is the 12th letter in the alphabet, but we count from 0 so 'l' is the 11th letter in what we would call the alphabet array.`'l' = 11, 'e' would = 4, 'm' = 12, 'o' = 14, 'n' = 13`. So if you wanted to encrypt the message "attack at dawn", each character would have its own letter from the key it corresponds to. It then adds the number corresponding to the key letter to the message letter and then you've encrypted it. Example below.

```
                  plain text:       attack at dawn
                  key:              lemonl em onle
                  encrypted:        lxfopv ef rnhr
```

Taking a look at the code and comments will also help. My problem is that the for loops that are supposed to actually encrypt the message are not working properly. I can't see any problems with the code, but output isn't correct so it must be a logical error maybe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string key;
    int keySize;
    char keyChar[5];
    int keyInteger[5];
    bool keyLoop = true;
    //makes sure key is 5 characters longs.
    while (keyLoop) {
        cout << "enter in the 5 letter key: ";
        cin >> key;
        keySize = key.size();
        if (keySize < 5 || keySize > 5) {
            cout << "Invalid key." << endl;
    }
    else {
        //obtains each individual character and places it into the array keyChar.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            keyChar[i] = key[i];
        }
        keyLoop = false;
    }
}

char alphabet[52]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
//finds the place of the element in keyChar and stores it as an int in the array keyInteger. This is setting up the key for encryption.
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (keyChar[x] == alphabet[i]) {
            keyInteger[x] = i;
        }
    }
}
//This just displays the values of keyInt. This code was included to make sure the program was storing the right values.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << keyInteger[i] << endl;
}

string secretMessage;

cin.ignore();
//user input their secret message
cout << "Enter your secret message: ";
getline(cin, secretMessage);
//gets size of message and creates variable to modify when we're ready to encrypt the message. 
int secretMessageSize = secretMessage.size();
cout << secretMessageSize << endl;
string newMessage = secretMessage;
int temp;

// This first loop goes through each character of the message. 
for (static int y = 0; y < secretMessageSize; y++) {
    // This loop keeps track of which keyInteger will be used for the encryption formula. 
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        // The if statement makes sure that the keyInteger isn't used until there is actually a character to be modified.
        if (secretMessage[y] == ' ') {
            //Just outputting the new message right now to make sure the program is running.
            cout << " ";
            a--;
        }
        else {
            //this loop goes runs until the character of secretMessage[y] is the same as the character at alphabet[i].
            //then it assigns temp to the value of i. This will be used in the encryption formula.
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                if (secretMessage[y] == alphabet[i]) {
                    temp = i;
                    break;
                }
                //this is all for testing purposes. LETTER should have the same letter in a row.
                cout << "LETTER " << secretMessage[y] << "           " << alphabet[i] << endl;
                //number should have the what number character the loop is on of the secretMessage. The number across should be the where that character was found in the alphabet array.
                cout << "NUMBER " << y << "           " << i << endl;
                //Key should only have one integer next to it. This should be whichever instance the loop that has a in it is at.
                cout << "KEY " << keyInteger[a] << endl;
                //This should give the actual character that should be replacing the character in secretMessage at whatever iteration it is at.
                //The encryption formula takes the integer that is used to address the character in the alphabet array. So if it were an 'a', then that integer would == 0;
                //Then it adds the keyInteger at whatever iteration the loop is at. If the keyword were lemon, and it was in its first iteration, a would = 0, and keyInteger[0] would equal 11.
                //The sum of these two values will give you the new character from the alphabet array. So alphabet[0+11] would = l. <-- this is a lower case L.
                cout << "CRYPT " << alphabet[keyInteger[a] + i] << endl;

            }
        }
        //this adds to y so that it keeps track of each character in the message, but we are also able to keep track of which keyInteger to use. 
        y++;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, define "not working properly". You should add an example of the output you get in your question.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the code written in C++ that does exactly what you are looking for. If anything is not working you can tell me in comments.

I have use the **find()** function in order to minimize the length of code and for better readability. I have primarily modified the **for()** loop that is encrypting the message (as mentioned by you also).

EDIT - Don't look for spaces only while encrypting. Anything other then alphabet should be printed as it is in the encrypted message. I have used **return(-1)** to do the same and checked it in the *if condition* in the *encryption loop*.

```
char alphabet[26]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int find(char character)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    {
        if (character == alphabet[i]) 
        {
            return (i);
        }
    }
    return (-1);
}

int main() 
{
    string key;
    int keySize;
    char keyChar[5];
    bool keyLoop = true;
    int keyInteger[5];

    while (keyLoop) 
    {
        cout << "enter in the 5 letter key: ";
        cin >> key;
        keySize = key.size();
        if (keySize < 5 || keySize > 5) 
        {
            cout << "Invalid key." << endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)    
            {
                keyChar[i] = key[i];
            }
            keyLoop = false;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
    {
        keyInteger[x] = find(keyChar[x]);
    }

    string secretMessage;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter your secret message: ";
    getline(cin, secretMessage);
    int secretMessageSize = secretMessage.size();
    string newMessage = secretMessage;
    int temp;

    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < secretMessageSize; i++)
    {
        if (x == 5)
            x = 0;

        if (find(secretMessage[i]) == -1)
            newMessage[i] = secretMessage[i];
        else
        {
            temp = (find(secretMessage[i]) + keyInteger[x])%26;
            newMessage[i] = alphabet[temp];
            x++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < secretMessageSize; i++)
    {
        cout << newMessage[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```